# Rails Form Label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, label

I am trying to generate a label in my rails.  The label should ultimately look like:

```
<label for="member_ids_index><span></span>collaborator.name</label>
```

Where index is the current iteration of my loop below, and collaborator.name is a string. For some reason, I can't get my f.label statement to properly generate this.  Can someone help me?  What I have so far is below.

```
<% if !@current_user.all_collaborators.nil? %>
  <% @current_user.all_collaborators.each_with_index do |collaborator, index| %>
    <%= check_box_tag "project_ids[#{index}]", collaborator.id %>
    <%= f.label :member_ids_, "<span></span>collaborator.name %>
    <br/>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `label_tag`:

```
<% if !@current_user.all_collaborators.nil? %>
  <% @current_user.all_collaborators.each_with_index do |collaborator, index| %>
    <%= check_box_tag "project_ids[#{index}]", collaborator.id %>
    <%= label_tag "member_ids_#{index}" do %>
      <span></span><%= collaborator.name %>
    <% end %>
    <br/>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```